# Access Foreign key items for SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, mysql, django, pandas

I would need your support/advice again, as I am just a hobby programmer.

I am storing data for a data analysis in mysql and access through django/phpmyadmin.

I think it is better than just storing in a text file.

For the real analysis I download the latest data then using SQLAlchemy to pandas.

Here is the issue:

To have the data structured, I use in django/mysql foreign keys, e.g.

```
class Analyse(models.Model):
   company = models.ForeignKey('analysen.Company', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='analyse')
  ... other fields

class Company(models.Model):
identification = models.CharField(max_length=100, primary_key=True)  
name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
```

The table for the analysis is "Analyse", however, in my pandas aggregation I would like to use after "downloading" with SQLAlchemy also the company name, so a different field of class Company than the primary key.

Which is the easiest solution without changing too much?

I believe this is not too complicated, I just do not find the solution right now.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Kind regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe my question was too easy or I described it in a misleading way. What I found is that I just need an inner join with the right command in SQL and then run this through SQLAlchemy.

An example can be found here:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/129023/selecting-data-from-another-table-using-a-foreign-key

Just in case someone has a similar issue.